# Setting up Dockerrun.aws.json in Elastic Beanstalk environment for multi-container configurations

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy my app to elastic beanstalk. Currently, everything works locally and it even works on elastic beanstalk, but the problem is that there is only one docker container explicitly defined and is shown as running in ECS. I am not sure how to effectively identify the "image" tag for each container. The code is deployed using CodePipeline. I am not particularly familiar with AWS and have been having significant difficulty expanding the container to show that each of the containers identified in the docker-compose-prod.yaml is running separately. I am concerned about scaling in the current configuration, as it is my understanding that if the program scales due to increased load all containers will increase, even if they are not necessarily needed. What is the proper way to define the Dockerrun.aws.json file and possibly the buildspec.yml file?

Dockerrun.aws.json.template:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "web",
      "image": "$REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 500,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Docker-compose-prod.yaml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build: ./app
    command: gunicorn appname.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:1339
    entrypoint: ./entrypoint-prod.sh
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app/
      - static_volume:/usr/src/app/static
      - media_volume:/usr/src/app/media
    expose:
      - 1339
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    depends_on:
      - redis
  nginx:
    build: ./app/nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/usr/src/app/static
      - media_volume:/usr/src/app/media
    ports:
      - 8085:80
    depends_on:
      - web
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
  celery:
      build: ./app
      command: celery -A appname worker -l info
      volumes:
        - ./app/:/usr/src/app/
      env_file:
        - ./.env.dev
      depends_on:
        - redis
  celery-beat:
    build: ./app
    command: celery -A appname beat -l info
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app/
    env_file:
      - ./.env.dev
    depends_on:
      - redis
volumes:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

buildspec.yml

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
    - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR....
    - aws --version
    - $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION)
    - COMMIT_HASH=$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | cut -c 1-7)
    - REPOSITORY_URI=number.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/appname-production
    - IMAGE_TAG=${COMMIT_HASH:=latest}
  build:
    commands:
    - echo Build started on `date`
    - echo Building the Docker image....
    - cd app
    - docker pull $REPOSITORY_URI:latest
    - docker build -t $REPOSITORY_URI:latest .
    - docker tag $REPOSITORY_URI:latest $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
  post_build:
    commands:
    - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest
    - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
    - cd ..
    - envsubst < "Dockerrun.aws.json.template" > "Dockerrun.aws.json"
artifacts:
  files:
    - Dockerrun.aws.json
```

Comment: Your `Dockerrun.aws.json` defins only one container. If you want to run multiple ones, you would have to define all of them in `Dockerrun.aws.json`.

Comment: @Marcin Yes, that is what I was asking was how to effectively define the containers. I'm not sure how to and I think the problem comes from effectively identifying the image tag and I'm not sure how to identify that. That's why I included the buildspec to show how the repository is stored. Sorry if that was not clear.